# Getting current location in Skobbler but only once

Tags: android, skmaps

By initializing update requests with `SKCurrentPositionProvider` and implementing `SKCurrentPositionListener` one can receive location updates. But is there a method to request the current location only once without any updating?

Answer (score 2):

Request the position once (`SKCurrentPositionProvider.requestLocationUpdates()`) and after that stop the further calls using  `SKCurrentPositionProvider.stopLocationUpdates()`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [getCurrentGPSPosition](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/com/skobbler/ngx/map/SKMapSurfaceView.html#getCurrentGPSPosition(boolean)) API

Comment: ``getCurrentGPSPosition()`` only works if a GPS Position was reported to the mapView before. And for reporting you need the GPS Position taken by  SKCurrentPositionProvider. It would be greate if there were a one-time-GPS-Position method.

Comment: `getCurrentGPSPosition()` is not available anymore in the newest SDK 3.0.2.